# TypeError: Cannot read property 'language' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to run *App-test.js* file provided by react native in *__test__* that is

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../src/app';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

Jest in **package.json** looks like this

```
...
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native)/"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": true
    },
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
...
```

I'm using package **react-native-localization** that is working fine in app but giving error while running jest, that is:

```
__tests__/App-test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'language' of undefined

       5 | import fr from './fr';
       6 | 
    >  7 | let localize = new LocalizedStrings({
         |                ^
       8 |     en: en,
       9 |     fr: fr
      10 | });

      at Object.customLanguageInterface (node_modules/react-native-localization/lib/LocalizedStrings.js:49:23)
      at LocalizedStrings.call (node_modules/localized-strings/lib/LocalizedStrings.js:67:42)
      at new LocalizedStrings (node_modules/react-native-localization/lib/LocalizedStrings.js:63:117)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/common/language/localizeController.js:7:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/containers/auth/launchScreen.js:25:1)

  console.error node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:30
```

**localizeController.js** is

```
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-native-localization';

import en from './en';
import fr from './fr';

let localize = new LocalizedStrings({
    en: en,
    fr: fr
});

export default localize;
```

Using it like this in launchScreen

```
import localize from '@common/language/localizeController';

...

<Text style={styles.titleText}>{localize.Title}</Text>

...
```

As this **localize** is used in all components, I can't test any component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create **jest-setup.js** file (if already not exists) and add following lines in that

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

NativeModules.ReactLocalization = {
    language: 'en',
};
```

now add this to **package.json**, now JEST in package.json looks like this.

```
...
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native|react)/"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/jest-setup.js"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": true
    },
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
...
```

Now this error is gone.
[Source](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization/issues/82)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and issue got resolved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are `en` and `fr` objects containing a `Title` property?

`en.js` should look something like:

```
export default {
   en: {
    Title: "some title in english"
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes they have, working fine when I run application.

Answer (score 0):

As *Ghayoor ul Haq* suggested, only the first step is enough for me. It solved the issue.

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

NativeModules.ReactLocalization = {
    language: 'en',
};
```